# JAXB schema validation error with CXF - JAXBException occurred : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, cxf

I have a **REST** service with **CXF 3.0.1** which accepts an **XML** message in a **HTTP POST** payload. The **XML** payload is getting unmarshalled to an Object by **JAXB**.

I am trying to validate the **XML** through an **XSD** schema and I have configured the **XSD** in **CXF** but I keep getting the error below

**JAXBException occurred : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'incident'.. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'incident'..**

**NOTE: incident is my root element**

What I understand from that is that **XSD** is successfully registered by **CXF** but something is wrong in the **JAXB** side.

I have tried many possible solutions related to that error but none worked.

Any ideas

Thanks

Here is my configuration

**Service**

```
@Path("incident") 
public class CreateIncident { 
        @POST 
        @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) 
        public Response createIncident(Incident incident) { 
                        //code 
        } 
}
```

**JAXB Object**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "incident") 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class Incident extends Event { 
        public Incident() { 
                super("incident"); 
        } 

        @XmlElement
        private String importProfile;

        @XmlElement
        private String eventTitle; 

        public String getImportProfile() { 
                return importProfile; 
        } 

        public void setImportProfile(String importProfile) { 
                this.importProfile = importProfile; 
        } 

        public String getEventTitle() {
                return eventTitle;
        }

        public void setEventTitle(String eventTitle) {
                this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
        }
}
```

**Event:**

```
public class Event {

    String eventType;

    public Event(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getEventType(){
        return eventType;
    }
}
```

**My XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.ba.com/schema/BAassystWrapper/incident"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="incident">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="importProfile">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="string">
                            <minLength value="1"></minLength>
                            <maxLength value="254"></maxLength>
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </element>
                <element name="eventTitle">
                    <simpleType>
                        <restriction base="string">
                            <minLength value="1"></minLength>
                            <maxLength value="890"></maxLength>
                        </restriction>
                    </simpleType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

**The XML that I pass**

```
<incident>
    <importProfile>Test text</importProfile>
    <eventTitle>Test text</eventTitle>
</incident>
```

**CXF Config**

```
<jaxrs:server address="/">
                <jaxrs:schemaLocations>
                        <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:xsd/incident.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
                </jaxrs:schemaLocations>
                <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                        <bean class="com.ba.sysman.services.events.CreateIncident"></bean>
                </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                <jaxrs:features>
                        <cxf:logging/>
                </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: Can we see your event class

Comment: @KarthikPrasad I have updated the question with the Event class

Answer (score 1):

THe root elements need to be namespace qualified.   Thus, the incoming XML needs to be something like:

```
<incident xmlns="http://www.ba.com/.......">
```

Comment: Daniel I have added the targetNamespace of the XSD to the root element of the incoming XML but I get this error: 

`JAXBException occurred : unexpected element (uri:"http://www.ba.com/schema/BAassystWrapper/incident", local:"incident"). Expected elements are <{}attachment>,<{}incident>.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not defined namesapce in `@XmlRootElement` remove the namespace from the input.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "incident") 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Event.class}) 
public class Incident extends Event { 
        public Incident() { 
                super("incident"); 
        }

    //fields, getters and setters
}
```

And in event class add default constructor

```
public Event(){

}
```

However its better to use `xjc plugin` and `wadl2java/wsdl2java plugin` and generate jaxb classes from xsd, which would save lots of time when you change xsd frequently and also use xmlns